# How do I write this complicated formula in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, markdown

I have been trying for days to figure out how to write this formula in R markdown...

[image: Formula]

...but I didn't find anything on the web.
Can you help me please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  x_1 = \left(\begin{array}{c}x_{11}\\\vdots\\x_{1p}\end{array}\right),
  \cdots,
  x_n = \left(\begin{array}{c}x_{n1}\\\vdots\\x_{np}\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

The array is used to stack elements and the `\left(` `\right)` pair provides the enclosing parenthesis.

Does not require any package and can probably be pasted as is in R.

[image]